# How to pass a variable to data-target data-toggle in AngularJS/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to execute this code

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target={{form.$invalid ? '#errorP2' : '#infoDiv'}}
```

which will toggle either info or error according to the form validity.

How can I do that ?

AngularJS : 1.4  --- Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just see something like this in the rendered markup :

```
data-target="{{ ng-binding"form.$invalid ? '#errorP2' : '#infoDiv'}}
```

or similar. Wrap it into qoutes so angular have a chance to parse the expression, and use an expression. 1.4.x *do* support ternarys :

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{form.$invalid==true ? '#errorP2' : '#infoDiv'}}"
```